# Search Woocommerce categories via API with quotes in the name

Tags: json, wordpress, woocommerce, woocommerce-rest-api

I need to query `woocommerce` via API v1 to retrieve category ID based on category name. I'm doing it in PHP

```
    $params = ['search' => "MATÉRIEL D'ARTISTES"];
    $category = $woocommerce->get('products/categories', $params);
```

I have an error about signature not valid

```
Error: Signature invalide - La signature fournie ne correspond pas.[woocommerce_rest_authentication_error]
```

If I remove the quote and make it "MATÉRIEL D ARTISTES" I have no errors but search doesn't return anything since it is not the same as in DB. If I try to escape de quote, I also have the error.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

As a fix, I have saved the quote in html encode special char :  ’ Search using this char works fine, and the category name on public pages is displayed correctly.